# Can I safely use Git (Version control) to save and manage Akai MPC pattern and song files? Does anyone have experience with this?

Tags: midi, backups, project-management

Can I safely use Git (Version control) to save and manage Akai MPC pattern and song files? Does anyone have experience with this? (the sequencer plays many midi modules)

This is an example of a 'song' and it's samples, .all, and .prg files.

[image]

As far as I can tell... the file format is binary. Is that not a text file?

RFL.ALL

```
246c 0200 4d50 4331 3030 3020 414c 4c20
312e 3030 0000 0000 5246 4c2d 3100 0000
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 74c1 0000
5246 4c2d 3200 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000 0000 8483 0000 5246 4c2d 3300 0000
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 c4f2 0000
5246 4c2d 3400 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000 0000 b42b 0100 5246 4c2d 3500 0000
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 5456 0100
5246 4c2d 3600 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000 0000 c480 0100 5246 4c2d 3700 0000
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 a4c5 0100
5246 4c2d 3800 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000 0000 84f9 0100 5246 4c2d 3900 0000
...
... (lots of that)
```

RFL.PGM

```
042a 0000 4d50 4331 3030 3020 5047 4d20
312e 3030 0000 0000 3930 3942 4431 3100
0000 0000 0000 0000 004f 007f 0000 0000
0030 3942 4430 3100 0000 0000 0000 0000
0064 007f 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000 0000 0000 0000 0064 007f 0000 0000
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
...
...
```

None of the tags I expect are available, so I suspect that I am posting in the wrong forum. Please advise.

Comment: Are you just looking to back-up your projects or are you wanting to maintain a history of changes over time (for rolling back to previous versions)?

Comment: Backup and rolling back if something bad happens. No merge or diffs needed though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Git (and pretty much any other version control system) can handle all files, even binary ones.
However, it is not possible to do things like `diff` or merging that require to look at parts of a file; you can just replace the entire binary file with a newer version. (It would be possible to add external helper tools to do these things, but that would require that you knew the format.)

Comment: OK. That's what I'm looking for. I don't need to diff things, but I may need to branch or revisit old states. I just want to be sure that the files won't be corrupted somehow.